# MeteorJS gives error on start: no such package: 'wrench'

Tags: meteor, meteorite

My MeteorJS app used to have Wrench package, but now it is removed from the app. It used to be under /packages folder. Also all references to the Wrench are removed. Still, when running 'meteor' command, it gives error and refuses to launch:

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'wrench'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Running mrt install, mrt update didn't helped. Searching through the app there are no 'wrench' occurrences. I'm pretty much out of ideas where Meteor finding references to Wrench, and how to remove those.

Comment: did you check smart.json file ?

Comment: did you check /$yourAppDir/.meteor/packages?

Comment: That .meteor/packages was it! Thanks. Removed 'wrench' line from there, and now it works.

Comment: In future if you remove packages with 'meteor remove' that will take care of that for you.